# How to sort the documents we got from FIND command in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection of around 10 million records. In that it has companyID and employee level, both are indexed in ascending order.

When I write a query as `db.collection.find("companyID":"XXX")`, mongo returns results very fast, but when I apply sorting on that

```
db.collection.find("companyID":"XXX").sort({"empLevel":1})
```

its taking a lot of time as for that companyID we have 100000 records.

Though both the fields are indexed, its taking a lot of time to process and return the results. Please help how to solve these kind of issues...

Comment: data and code samples please

Comment: Sort the results client side if you really care that much about the database speed. Or don't use a NoSQL database if sorting is an operation that's performed often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution In java

import these

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Sorts.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;
```

Code

```
MongoCollection <Document> images = mongo.getCollection("nameofcollection");    
Bson sort = descending("empLevel");
FindIterable<Document> iterdoc = album.find(eq("companyID",XXX)).sort(sort);
```